# For loop not calling function more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x

My for variable in sequence stops after the first iteration. I can't seem to tell where the issue is.

I am developing a simple program that opens a student's files at a certain time based on the subject and class time.

```
# imported functions here
. 
.

subjects = list(map(str, input("""Which subjects would you like to set up?
                               \nSeparate each subject with commas.
                               """).split(", ")))
print("Your subjects are: " + str(subjects))

for subject in subjects:

    def openFileForSubject():
        timeOfSubject = input("What time is your " + subject + """ class? Enter
                              in 24-hr time (HH:MM): """)
        fileName = input("""Which file would you like to open? Include
                         entire pathname: """)
        greeting = input("Leave yourself a start-up message! Enter: ")
        print("Registered!")

        def openDocument():
            subprocess.call(['open', fileName])
            print(greeting)

        schedule.every().day.at(timeOfSubject).do(openDocument)

        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(2)

    openFileForSubject()
```

The code under `def openFileForSubject()` works great, the only issue is it doesn't repeat for the second (or third etc.) subject entered in the `subjects` input.

After the codes iterates through the first subject and prints `Registered!` it doesn't prompt for the second subject and just continues to run in the background.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: To make sure I understand: the intent is for the program to run constantly 24/7, and pop up the reminders at the appropriate daily time for each student? You might want to look into `cron` (or the Windows Task Scheduler) for this.

Comment: As an aside, nesting function definitions like this is rarely what you actually want in Python. `Flat is better than nested`; it's easier to understand what's going on if all the definitions are at top level, and it's only *necessary* to nest them if you're doing advanced tricks with closures.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's about right. Thanks for the advice! I will look into it. I'm using a Mac and not sure if that affects anything? 

I see your point also about the nesting and will definitely keep it in mind!

Comment: I quickly verified that `schedule` works like I expected it to, and put together an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start out by un-nesting the `openFileForSubject` definition for clarity, and cleaning up a couple of other details:

```
def openFileForSubject(subject):
    timeOfSubject = input(
        # String formatting makes this easier.
        f"What time is your {subject} class? Enter in 24-hr time (HH:MM): "
    )
    fileName = input("Which file would you like to open? Include entire pathname: ")
    greeting = input("Leave yourself a start-up message! Enter: ")
    print("Registered!")

    # I'll leave this one nested for now;
    # the next block will show how to un-nest it.
    def openDocument():
        subprocess.call(['open', fileName])
        print(greeting)

    schedule.every().day.at(timeOfSubject).do(openDocument)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(2)

subjects = input(
    # Here's another trick for line-wrapping long literal strings in text.
    # Because this is inside parentheses, line-continuation characters are not needed.
    "Which subjects would you like to set up?\n" +
    "Separate each subject with commas."
).split(', ')
# The results of .split() are already strings; no need to clean them up.

print("Your subjects are:", str(subjects))

for subject in subjects:
    openFileForSubject(subject)
```

The issue, as noted, is the infinite loop at the end of `openFileForSubject`. However, we only need to start the `run_pending` loop once anyway (as seen in the documentation example), and we want the scheduler to know about every task before that loop starts. So, evidently, that loop belongs outside and after:

```
# This time, also with some pep8 conventions for naming, name suggestions, etc.
from functools import partial # in addition to other imports.

def open_document(filename, greeting): # explicitly pass in the information.
    subprocess.call(['open', filename])
    print(greeting)

def setup_scheduling(subject):
    time_of_day = input(
        f"What time is your {subject} class? Enter in 24-hr time (HH:MM): "
    )
    filename = input("Which file would you like to open? Include entire pathname: ")
    greeting = input("Leave yourself a start-up message! Enter: ")
    schedule.every().day.at(time_of_day).do(
        # use functools.partial to bind the parameters ahead of time.
        partial(open_document, filename, greeting)
    )
    print("Registered!")

subjects = input(
    "Which subjects would you like to set up?\n" +
    "Separate each subject with commas."
).split(', ')

print("Your subjects are:", str(subjects))

for subject in subjects:
    setup_scheduling(subject)

# Finally, the polling loop.
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Amazing. I need a few minutes to process all of this but before I go on I want to quickly say a huge thanks for this massive help! BRB after I read haha

Comment: Let's just say I've got major tunnel vision (just starting out with code) and could never have imagined my code like this. It works, all makes sense to my beginner mind and is so much more organised! Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there are any shortcuts - the important factors are experience and discipline, both of which take time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple :

```
while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(2)
```

You have an endless `while` loop so it won't go into the next iteration. You need some conditions to break from it, or not use the loop at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
   while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(2)
```

That block of code there will never return, meaning your code can never continue on.

--EDIT-- I didn't know what the `schedule` library was actually doing- there's an easier way to fix this. Leaving the asyncio code for an example.

Fix this by moving the event loop (the `while True` part of the code) outside of your for loop. Loop through your files, add your tasks to the schedule, and after the loop exits do the "run forever" bit.

---

For this problem, I'd probably pick asyncio. The learning curve can be a bit steep for ANY python concurrency stuff though :/

```
# async def makes the function return a coroutine that can be executed on an event loop
async def run_loop(subjects):
    for subject in subjects:

        async def openFileForSubject():
            timeOfSubject = input("What time is your " + subject + """ class? Enter
                              in 24-hr time (HH:MM): """)
            fileName = input("""Which file would you like to open? Include
                         entire pathname: """)
            greeting = input("Leave yourself a start-up message! Enter: ")
            print("Registered!")

            def openDocument():
                proc = await create_subprocess_exec(['open', fileName])
                await proc.wait()
                print(greeting)

            schedule.every().day.at(timeOfSubject).do(openDocument)

            while True:
                schedule.run_pending()
                # time.sleep is blocking- we have to use the async version
                await asyncio.sleep(2)

    # This will add a task to the event loop for each subject.
    asyncio.create_task(openFileForSubject())

# Start the event loop. It will exit when all the tasks finish (never here, until you
# sigkill it
asyncio.run(run_event_loop(subject_input))
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `schedule` in OP's code comes from some kind of threading library that does the work of asyncio here.

Comment: `import subprocess`
`import schedule`
`import time`
If that helps!

Comment: Thank you for this answer! asyncio is definitely new to me but I'm happy to check it out and try what you suggested.

Comment: Specifically the third-party `schedule` documented here? https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes. I don't think I've seen this specific website before though, so thanks for the link!

Comment: Oh, true- I thought it was the calendar schedule method. In that case, this is a terrible answer! Just move the "while True" loop out of your for loop.